# Python 3 Player not moving

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
       pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.x = 32
       self.y = 32
       self.yspeed = 0
       self.xspeed = 0
       self.image = pg.draw.rect(screen, yellow, (self.x, self.y, tilesize, tilesize))
       self.rect = pg.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)

    def moveRight(self):
        self.xspeed = 5
        self.yspeed = 0

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.xspeed = -5
        self.yspeed = 0

    def moveUp(self):
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.yspeed = -5

    def moveDown(self):
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.yspeed = 5

playing = True
while playing:

    p = Player()

    for event in pg.event.get():

        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            playing = False

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_d:
                p.moveRight()
            if event.key == pg.K_a:
                p.moveLeft()
            if event.key == pg.K_w:
                p.moveUp()
            if event.key == pg.K_s:
                p.moveDown()

    p.x += p.xspeed
    p.y += p.yspeed

    screen.fill(black)
    p.__init__()
    drawGrid()
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Confused as to why my player is not moving? Just making a simple game loop where the player continually goes in one direction until pressed otherwise 888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888

Comment: don't do `p.__init__()` - when you do `p = Player()` the it automatically execute `p.__init__()`. if you have to reset data in player then create method in `Player()` for reseting data.

Answer (score 1):

Big mistake: don't create `p = Player()` inside `while playing` because it recreates `Player()` in every loop so it reset all information.

Create `Player()` before `while`

And don't use `p.__init__()` because it reset informations too.

To draw it you need

```
screen.blit(p.image, p.rect)
```

But I see another mistake

```
self.image = pg.draw.rect(screen, yellow, (self.x, self.y, tilesize, tilesize))
```

`pygame.draw.rect()` doesn't create image, it draws directly on screen and returns `Rect()`.
It needs more changes.

---

**EDIT:** Code could look like this:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
       pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.x = 32
       self.y = 32
       self.yspeed = 0
       self.xspeed = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
       pg.draw.rect(screen, yellow, (self.x, self.y, tilesize, tilesize))

    def moveRight(self):
        self.xspeed = 5
        self.yspeed = 0

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.xspeed = -5
        self.yspeed = 0

    def moveUp(self):
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.yspeed = -5

    def moveDown(self):
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.yspeed = 5

p = Player()
playing = True
while playing:

    for event in pg.event.get():

        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            playing = False

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_d:
                p.moveRight()
            if event.key == pg.K_a:
                p.moveLeft()
            if event.key == pg.K_w:
                p.moveUp()
            if event.key == pg.K_s:
                p.moveDown()

    p.x += p.xspeed
    p.y += p.yspeed

    screen.fill(black)
    p.draw()
    drawGrid()
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Though that is helpful, but my problem is still not fixed. Anything else you can advise?